# RewriteRule ssl conf combining various

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I need to Rewrite every Dir to https, www and trailing slash and for SEO i need every redirect with only one 301.

The first twoo are solved, but the third doesn't work if de URW comes with www (it returns a 302 if a URL exist, and then write de trailing slash), but i've a rule to handle that case, can you see something wrong?

ssl.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what redirected URL you're getting. Also what is your expected result?

Comment: Sorry, i realized that i haven't the www entry in my hosts... Now it works fine!!

The rules above works perfect to rewrite wit a 301 for example:

`https://test.com/somefolder to https://www.test.com/somefolder/` or 
`https://test.com/somefolder/ to https://www.test.com/somefolder/`

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, the rules above works fine, the problem was with my hosts file that hadn't the www entry to test.

I leave the Rule for help anyone if needed.